# New command for bold characters in math mode

Tags: math-mode, bold

I am using bold characters u,v,w,x in math mode. Is there a way to make a new command for that? Now I always have to type `\bm{u}`.

Comment: What about `\newcommand{\bu}{\bm{u}}`

Answer (score 5):

You can go

```
\bmdefine\bu{u}
```

then use `\bu` instead of `\bm{u}` this is a bit quicker than using `\bm` every time as it only has to work out the corresponding bold font once. (That wouldn't be the case if you used 
`\newcommand\bu{\bm{u}}` which would expand to doing `\bm` every tine.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have :

```
\def\,#1{\mathbf{#1}}
```

When I want to type a bold character I just write

```
\,u
```

Comment: probably not a good idea to redefine `\,` -- that is the existing convention for a thin space, in both plain tex and latex.